# Allow user to change style of a page

Tags: javascript, php, css, ajax

Creating a CMS and I want to create buttons for user to style the page.

```
//customize.php

<body class = "body">
<input type = "color" name = "bgColor" id = "bgColor">
<button onclick = "changeColor()">Change Color</button>
</body>
```

I'm parsing my css in php so I can update the css through ajax.

```
//style.js
function changeColor(){
   var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
   var getbgColor = document.getElementById("bgColor").value;

   request.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(request.status == 200 && request.readyState == 4){

          //I want to send $mycolor back to the client side so user can see
          //how their page would look like

          var asx = request.responseText;
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = asx;
        }
     };
    request.open("GET","mode.php?theColor=" + getbgColor,true);
    request.send();
```

Parsing css in php

```
   //mode.php

   <?php

       header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8;");

       $mycolor = (isset($_GET['theColor'])) ? $_GET['theColor']: false;

    ?>

     .body{
           background-color: <?php echo $mycolor; ?>;
        }
```

I have another file call showPage.php that will have the style manufactured from the customize.php file, but I can't get it to work. What I keep getting is false from $mycolor. Can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I haven't taught myself jQuery yet, so if you assist, please no jQuery. (thanks for the assistance)

Comment: Au.. why not just change the color directly with javascript? You are prone to XSS injection by the way, always escape your stuff properly (`echo htmlentities($mycolor);`)

Comment: @BasvanStein Even if I change the color directly with javascript, I would need that showPage?id= //whatever # it is in the db, to remember which color it was changed to. I don't want to store any css in the database, which is why I hoping to update the parse css.